# basicHttpBinding doesn't use custom ServiceCredentials

Tags: c#, wcf, security, authentication, authorization

I have a WCF-Service with custom ServiceCredentials implemented, they use a custom ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager which is using a custom UserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator.

This is working with my netTcpBinding but I wanted to implement a WebClient which should connect over basicHttpBinding.. But basicHttpBinding doesn't use my custom ServiceCredentials..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using custom credentials with basicHttpBinding only works when you're using SSL.
The credentials won't be submitted and your validator won't be called when you're not using SSL.